# wp_query with multiple arguments with AND

Tags: php, wp-query

```
$loop3 = new WP_Query( array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 10000, 
    'post_type' => 'volunteers',  
    'meta_key' => 'state',
    'meta_value' => $stateselect,
    'meta_compare' => '=',
    'meta_key' => 'volunteer_type',
    'meta_value' => 'painter',
    'meta_compare' => '=',
    ) );
```

Hello.  I'm new to PHP and WordPress.  I'm having trouble understanding how WP_Query works.  I'm trying to get a dataset that looks like this pseudocode:

state=$stateselect AND volunteer_type=painter

The code above seems to be rewriting 'meta_key' and returning results from all 'states', since 'volunteer_type' appears to be overwriting.  How do I ...

- Retrieve the results of two different criteria,
- do equivalent of AND between the two different meta_key criterias?

Also, I want to sort the results by a meta_key that is not in the arguments.  e.g. There's a field called 'Section' which is alpanumerical.  How is sort ASC or DESC done on a field that is not part of the arguments?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the newer `meta_query` methodology...

You establish a `meta_query` and then use arrays for the different conditions you want met, preface them with the relationship `relation => 'AND'` or `relation => 'OR'`

```
$loop3 = new WP_Query( array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 10000, 
    'post_type' => 'volunteers',  
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' = 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'state',
            'value' => $stateselect,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'volunteer_type',
            'value' => 'painter',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
) );
```

Codex has a write-up here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters

***Note***
That's a lot, like A LOT, of `posts_per_page`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [meta_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters):

```php
$loop3 = new WP_Query( array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 10000, 
    'post_type' => 'volunteers',  
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'state',
            'value'   => $stateselect,
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'volunteer_type',
            'value'   => 'painter',
        ),
));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).